# How to calculate Williams %R in RStudio?

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function to calculate Williams %R on data in R. Here is my code:

```
getSymbols('AMD', src = 'yahoo', from = '2018-01-01')

wr = function(high, low, close, n) {
  highh = runMax((high),n)
  lowl = runMin((low),n)
  -100 * ((highh - close) / (highh - lowl))
}

williampr = wr(AMD$AMD.High, AMD$AMD.Low, AMD$AMD.Close, n = 10)
```

After implementing a buy/sell/hold signal, it returns integer(0):

```
## 1 = BUY, 0 = HOLD, -1 = SELL
## implement Lag to shift the time back to the previous day
tradingSignal = Lag(
  ## if wpr is greater than 0.8, BUY
  ifelse(Lag(williampr) > 0.8 & williampr < 0.8,1,
  ## if wpr signal is less than 0.2, SELL, else, HOLD
  ifelse(Lag(williampr) > 0.2 & williampr < 0.2,-1,0)))
## make all missing values equal to 0
tradingSignal[is.na(tradingSignal)] = 0
## see how many SELL signals we have
which(tradingSignal == "-1")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For people like myself who aren't familiar with the field, it would help if you included something about what Williams %R is. Right now I can't tell what you're trying to get exactly

Comment: The TTR package has a Williams %R function already defined.  Be sure to look at the Op, Hi, Lo, Cl, Ad functions in quantmod.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been a good idea to identify that you were using the package `quantmod` in your question.

There are two things preventing this from working.

You didn't inspect what you expected! Your results in `williampr` are all negative. Additionally, you multiplied the values by 100, so 80% is 80, not .8. I removed `-100 *`.

I have done the same thing so many times.

```
wr = function(high, low, close, n) {
  highh = runMax((high),n)
  lowl = runMin((low),n)
  ((highh - close) / (highh - lowl))
}
```

That's it. It works now.

```
which(tradingSignal == "-1")
#  [1]   13   15   19   22   39   71   73   84   87  104  112  130  134  136  144  146  151  156  161  171  175
# [22]  179  217  230  255  268  288  305  307  316  346  358  380  386  404  449  458  463  468  488  492  494
# [43]  505  510  515  531  561  563  570  572  574  594  601  614  635  642  644  646  649  666  668  672  691
# [64]  696  698  719  729  733  739  746  784  807  819  828  856  861  872  877  896  900  922  940  954  968
# [85]  972  978  984  986 1004 1035 1048 1060
```